# how do you repeat the same jquery code on a css class element?

Tags: jquery

i have this jquery code

```
 $('.slickbox').hide();

 // toggles the slickbox on clicking the noted link  
  $('.slick-toggle').click(function() {
    $('.slickbox').toggle(400);
    return false;
  });
```

and this applies to several div's with the same class on the page , however when i click on one  all of them open , what i could do is set an id instead of a class and repeat the same code for each id , is there a way to make it so that even with a class each div opens on its own independent of the others. 
Let me know if there is need for clarification as my descriptive skills are not the best

the HTML :

```
     <a href="#" class="slick-toggle">  
<img src="images/pc.de/plus.png" width="16" height="16" alt="new" /></a>
<div class="slickbox">
        New Video Category: <input type="text" name="video_link_youtube" value=""  />
       </div>
```

Comment: it should be doable! but we will need to see your html structure to figure out what selector combination to use :)

Comment: Are the `.slick-toggle` and `.slickbox` elements in lists? In that case, you could use indexes (the position of the element among its siblings) to determine which `.slick-toggle` element corresponds to which `.slickbox` element...

Comment: Can you show a sample of your markup?

Comment: It depends on how you've organized the DIVs.  You can use $(this) to get the element that's being clicked on, and something like $(this).parent() to get it's parent.  It would help to see what you've done in jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

instead of:

```
  $('.slick-toggle').click(function() {
    $('.slickbox').toggle(400);
    return false;
  });
```

do this:

```
  $('.slick-toggle').click(function() {
    $(this).toggle(400);
    return false;
  });
```

Comment: The `.slick-toggle` elements are the buttons that trigger the the display of the `.slickbox` elements, and the `.slickbox` elements are the elements which display is being triggered by the `.slick-toggle` elements. They're not the same elements.

Comment: no this dose not work for me , maybe iam tto much of a noob and doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.slickbox').hide();

// toggles the slickbox on clicking the noted link  
$('.slick-toggle').click(function() {
    $(this).toggle(400);
    return false;
});
```

Before you were calling toggle on all of your "$('.slick-toggle')"